# Slider with Thumbnail Navigator (JQUERY)

Tags: jquery

I have a question. I want to use  of thumbnail-06 source (that exists in skin).but when i add class jssort06  to my slideshow  it dos'nt work, 
I use this code

```
<style>
   . jssort06{
    position:absolute;
    width:240px;
    height:480px;
    }
 ... 
</style>
```

.....

..

Comment: Where is your `jQuery source codes`.

Comment: is the space between the period and class name a typo?  `. jssort06`

Comment: I mean you don't understand of period,please explain what's period?

Comment: period = "." aka full stop. is ". jssort06" how it exists in code? If so it should be ".jssort06"

Comment: May be in here i  mistake type but in my work i used copy and paste

Comment: And when i use thumbnail0-01.source i hav'nt any problem may be related to the jaquery code? Not to css code?